# GCM notification received on device does not start the application

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using https://github.com/kobakei/unity-gcm for GCM notifications in Unity3D. I receive the messages on the device. When I tap on the notification nothing happens. I expect the application to start. This is the log:

```
V/GCMRegistrar( 8441): Setting the name of retry receiver class tocom.kskkbys.unitygcmplugin.UnityGCMBroadcastReceiver
V/UnityGCMBroadcastReceiver( 8441): getGCMIntentServcieClassName
V/GCMBroadcastReceiver( 8441): GCM IntentService class: com.kskkbys.unitygcmplugin.UnityGCMIntentService
V/GCMBaseIntentService( 8441): Acquiring wakelock
D/ConnectivityService(  845): handleInetConditionHoldEnd: net=0, condition=100, published condition=100
V/GCMBaseIntentService( 8441): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-DynamicSenderIds-1
D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController( 1051): onReceive() - CONNECTIVITY_ACTION, INET_CONDITION_ACTION
V/UnityGCMIntentService( 8441): onMessage
V/UnityGCMIntentService( 8441): ticker: ticker
D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController( 1051): getUpdateDataNetType() - mDataNetType:15
D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController( 1051): updateDataNetType()
D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController( 1051): Nothing, mRoamingIconId = 0
V/UnityGCMIntentService( 8441): foo: bar
V/UnityGCMIntentService( 8441): from: xxxxx
V/UnityGCMIntentService( 8441): content_title: New Friend Request
V/UnityGCMIntentService( 8441): score: 123
V/UnityGCMIntentService( 8441): is_first: true
V/UnityGCMIntentService( 8441): content_text: test
V/UnityGCMIntentService( 8441): collapse_key: do_not_collapse
D/dalvikvm( 8441): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.company.app-23/libmain.so 0x42587730
D/dalvikvm( 8441): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.company.app-23/libmain.so 0x42587730
W/dalvikvm( 8441): No implementation found for native Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;.UnitySendMessage:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
W/System.err( 8441): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
W/System.err( 8441):    at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(Native Method)
W/System.err( 8441):    at com.kskkbys.unitygcmplugin.Util.sendMessage(Util.java:23)
W/System.err( 8441):    at com.kskkbys.unitygcmplugin.UnityGCMIntentService.onMessage(UnityGCMIntentService.java:50)
W/System.err( 8441):    at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:223)
W/System.err( 8441):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
W/System.err( 8441):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err( 8441):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
W/System.err( 8441):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
V/UnityGCMNotificationManager( 8441): showNotification
V/GCMBaseIntentService( 8441): Releasing wakelock
W/ContextImpl(  845): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1505 com.android.server.StatusBarManagerService.sendNotification:985 com.android.server.StatusBarManagerService.addNotification:674 com.android.server.NotificationManagerService$7.run:2157 android.os.Handler.handleCallback:733
```

and

```
W/ContextImpl(  845): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1505 com.android.server.StatusBarManagerService.sendNotification:985 com.android.server.StatusBarManagerService.removeNotification:710 com.android.server.NotificationManagerService.cancelNotificationLocked:2469 com.android.server.NotificationManagerService.access$5100:162 
D/STATUSBAR-StatusBarManagerService(  845): sendNotification(3) - 1
```

**EDIT:**
AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<!-- Android GCM Plugin -->
<receiver android:name="com.kskkbys.unitygcmplugin.UnityGCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="com.company.application" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="com.kskkbys.unitygcmplugin.UnityGCMIntentService" />
<!-- Android GCM Plugin -->

</application>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"    />


<!-- Android GCM Plugin -->
<permission android:name="com.company.application.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.company.application.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<!-- Android GCM Plugin -->
```

**EDIT2:**
This is the error that comes up in logcat when I touch the notification icon and expect the app to start.

```
 Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast:1505 com.android.server.StatusBarManagerService.sendNotification:985 com.android.server.StatusBarManagerService.removeNotification:710 com.android.server.NotificationManagerService.cancelNotificationLocked:2469 com.android.server.NotificationManagerService.access$5100:162
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logcat errors in the question don't have anything to do with the app not starting from the notification.

The problem was solved by LeshM @ https://github.com/kobakei/unity-gcm/issues/1

```
I found out that the gcm plugin is setting a specific unity activity as the pending intent of the notification.
As soon as I added the activity to my AndroidManifest.xml it worked!

These are the activities I defined:

<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
</activity>
<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity"
      android:launchMode="singleTask"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen">
 <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="unity" />
 <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
 <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
 </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Viewing your logcat it looks as if your NotificationListenerService is not working as it is expected to work. As you have not provided code, you may try out these probable solutions in order to make sure that the received broadcast is properly handled as notification and the tap on notification opens the relevant activity.

- There may be a kind of conflict on your device. The best way to deal with this is to clean up some space and re-install the app from the Google Play.
- Use below function instead of sendBroadcast(Intent intent).

  void sendBroadcastAsUser(Intent intent, UserHandle user)
  for example,

  context.sendBroadcastAsUser(newIntent, new UserHandle(UserHandle.USER_CURRENT));
- Make sure you have proper permissions in your app manifest file.

  ```
  <manifest package="com.example.gcm" ...> 
      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <uses-permission         android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
      <uses-permission   android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

  <permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

  <application ...>
      <receiver
          android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
          android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
              <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
          </intent-filter>
      </receiver>
      <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
  </application>

  </manifest>
  ```
- Follow the instructions in [this](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) document to know more about the client implementation.

Hope this would Help!!

Comment: I posted the manifest to the question. To me it seems working. I uninstalled the app from the device and rebuilt it. Didn't make a difference.

I didn't post any code because I use the unity-gcm plugin and it doesn't require any android code.